# Race-condition as a random number generator

Tags: c++, race-condition

I simulated a race-condition between threads in C++ by "pthread.h"
when running it, it gots error at a "random" loop iteration.

Can I use it as a random number generator?
And why?

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<thread>

static int counter = 0;

void increase() {
        register int i = counter;
        i++;
        counter = i;
}
void decrease() {
        register int i = counter;
        i--;
        counter = i;
}
int main() {
    std::thread *p1, *p2;
    register int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        i++;
        counter = 0;
        p1 = new std::thread(increase);
        p2 = new std::thread(decrease);
        p1->join();
        p2->join();
        delete p1;
        delete p2;
        if (counter) {
            std::fprintf(stderr, "Error at loop %d\n", i);
            std::exit(1);
        }
    }
    std::exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You don't cleanup the first thread in case second one fails to start. Otherwise — quite possible, but you probably won't have an idea of what the distribution is (Poisson?)

Comment: When you use C++, just use C++, why `pthread` instead of `std::thread`? Don't throw objects that are not `std::exception`. your question is not suitable for SO, but well, sure you can use it as some kind of random number generator. You just need to write appropriate interface for it and maybe investigate what kind of distribution will be produced.

Comment: This is not really C++ apart from throwing a `const char *`. Either adjust it to C++ (use std::thread, etc) or remove throwing and change tag to "C".

Comment: @Ptaq666 He is using the `register` keyword, which has been deprecated in `C++11`. So I assume he is not even using `C++11`, so no `std::thread` ;)

Comment: A race condition is equal to Undefined Behaviour. You don't want that in your program. It gives the compiler licence to do whatever it wants to your code. All bets are off and you can no longer depend on any behaviour you observe - *anywhere*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using random number generator in computing, one of the important properties is that replicable results. And also we want to have a predictable random sequence with a fixed distribution (uniform distribution typically).

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use it as a random number generator?

you really shouldn't use it as a random number.

> why?

you shouldn't because race conditions are undefined behavior.

this "random" number doesn't have a good entropy as it is depend on timing.

there are much better way to generate random numbers in `#include <random>`.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behavior should not be used as source (or one of sources) of entropy in C++ code even when it appears random. That is because anything like slight change in computer or compiler settings or upgrade of something or taking different computer may result with something lot less random.

Comment: It's *far worse* than that. If the program contains UB anywhere, the *entire* program is meaningless and the compiler is allowed to generate whatever code it wants for the *entire* program, not just the bit that invokes UB. So relying on UB for the random number generator might actually cause bugs in *other parts* of your program as well.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl On that case every C++ program that uses automatic storage for anything is meaningless since limitless automatic storage is impossible but behavior on case of potential exceeding of automatic storage limits is undefined by C++ standard.

Comment: it's only undefined if you *actually exceed* the storage limits. But the fact of the matter is that modern compilers *do* exploit UB quite aggressively, so you want to avoid it like the plague.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know. My position is that it is truly backwards of those compilers, I mean doing such aggressive exploitations instead of giving simple diagnostics.